# How do I resolve a Django query "'ExtractHour' object has no attribute 'split'" error?

Tags: python, sql, django, python-3.x, model

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I want to include a subquery in the criteria of a larger query.

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractHour
...
hour_filter = ExtractHour(ExpressionWrapper(
            F("article__created_on") + timedelta(0, avg_fp_time_in_seconds),
            output_field=models.DateTimeField()
        ),
)
query = StatByHour.objects.filter(hour_of_day=OuterRef(hour_filter))

...
```

The larger query that contains it is

```
qset = ArticleStat.objects.filter(                votes__gte=F("article__website__stats__total_score") / F(
                "article__website__stats__num_articles") *
                       Subquery(query.values('index'), outout_field=FloatField()) *
                       day_of_week_index)
```

However, when I run this, I get the error

```
'ExtractHour' object has no attribute 'split'
```

What does this mean and how I can adjust my filter so that this error goes away?

**Edit:** adding the model of the thing making the outer query ...

```
class ArticleStat(models.Model):
    objects = ArticleStatManager()
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articlestats')
    ...
    votes = models.FloatField(default=0, null=False)
```

Comment: Well why do you wwrap an `ExtractHour` in an `OuterRef`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS @WillemVanOnsem has pointed out:

> **Use OuterRef when a queryset in a Subquery needs to refer to a field from the outer query**. It acts like an F expression except that the check to see if it refers to a valid field isn’t made until the outer queryset is resolved.

And then you did:

```
query = StatByHour.objects.filter(hour_of_day=OuterRef(hour_filter))
```

where `hour_filter` is treated as a field lookup and Django is performing a sort of

```
hour_filter.split('__')
```

in order to gather the parts of the expected field lookup.

But `hour_filter` is here an `ExtractHour`, hence the error.

You could try to annotate your articles stats with the desired hour and then work on the result:

```
 hour_value = ExtractHour(
    ExpressionWrapper(
        F("article__created_on") + timedelta(0, avg_fp_time_in_seconds),
        output_field=models.DateTimeField()
    ),
)


qset = ArticleStat.objects.annotate(
    hour = hour_value
).filter(
     # ... and write your filter based on the annotate field (hour) here.
)
```

The whole thing could look like (I've not tested this, it's just an effort for pointing you out the right direction):

```
hour_value = ExtractHour(
    ExpressionWrapper(
        F("article__created_on") + timedelta(0, avg_fp_time_in_seconds),
        output_field=models.DateTimeField()
    ),
)


qset = ArticleStat.objects.annotate(
    hour = hour_value
).filter(
    votes__gte=F("article__website__stats__total_score") / 
               F("article__website__stats__num_articles") *
               F("hour") * day_of_week_index
)
```

**Addendum:**

If you still want to use a subquery here you can modify the one you already have in order to make it work on the annotated field:

```
query = StatByHour.objects.filter(hour_of_day=OuterRef('hour'))
```

Gook luck!

Comment: In your answer, you removed the subquery I'm trying to use.  "hour_value" is not plugged directly into the ArticleStat query but rather into the Subquery that is plugged directly into the ArticleStat query.  So you have "F("hour") * day_of_week_index" but I want "Subquery[that uses hour] * day_of_week_index".

Comment: Hey!  After trying what you suggested in your edit it appears to be working.  Wow taht's stumped me for so long!  Anyway I'm going to run a few more tests and then I'll come back and accept.

Answer (score 0):

The `OuterRef` is used to obtain a value from the parent query, but here you do not need a reference from the outer query at all.

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractHour

hour_filter = ExtractHour(
    ExpressionWrapper(
        F('article__created_on') + timedelta(0, avg_fp_time_in_seconds),
        output_field=models.DateTimeField()
    )
)
query = StatByHour.objects.filter(hour_of_day=hour_filter)
```

So you do not need an `OuterRef` here. As the [documentation on **`OuterRef`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.OuterRef) says:

> Use `OuterRef` when a queryset in a `Subquery` needs to **refer to a
>   field from the outer query**. It acts like an `F` expression except
>   that the check to see if it refers to a valid field isn’t made until
>   the outer queryset is resolved.

Comment: Thanks, but I do need to refer to a field from the outer query (the ArticleStat model).  Indeed, when I remove the OuterRef, I get an error, "Cannot resolve keyword 'article' into field. Choices are: hour_of_day, id, index, num_articles, total_score", which are all fields from the Subquery "StatByHour object.

Comment: @Dave: then there is clearly no relation between the `StatByHour` and the `Article` model? You really need to add relations, since otherwise Django can by know means understand what you aim to do. Is it possible to show the (relevant) parts of your models?

Comment: "article" is related to ArticleStat, so that's why I was using the OuterRef, since per what you have, I need to refer to a field from the outer query.  There's no relation between StatByHour and ArticleStat.  I'll add in the model soon.

Comment: @Dave: but as said before `OuterRef` expects a *string*: it is used to get a reference to a specif column in the outer query.

Comment: Oh thanks for this clarification, I didn't undersatnd that.  So I'm at a loss on how to proceed.  I included the model of what I want returned, I just don't know how to write a string.  Would I write "articlestat.article" or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `OuterRef` inside the `ExtractHour`:

```py
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractHour
...
query = StatByHour.objects.filter(
    hour_of_day=ExtractHour(ExpressionWrapper(
            # NOTE: `OuterRef()+something` works only on Django >= 2.1.0
            OuterRef("article__created_on") + timedelta(0, avg_fp_time_in_seconds),
            output_field=models.DateTimeField()
        ),
    )
)

qset = ArticleStat.objects.filter(
    votes__gte=(
        F("article__website__stats__total_score") 
        / 
        F("article__website__stats__num_articles") 
        *
        Subquery(
            query.values('index')[:1], 
            output_field=FloatField()
        ) 
        *
        day_of_week_index
    ),
)
```